# to get visits having end time between 20:00 to midnight (00:00)

Tags: sql, sql-server

from the table below, I need to get the visits which having EndTime between 20:00 to 00:00. (highlighted in yellow)

[image]

this is the query I am using now, but if I am not getting any result. if I change the time 00:00 to 23:59, I am getting the other two results, but not the one with endtime = 00:00.

```
Select VisitID, StartTime, duration, dateadd(minute,Duration,StartTime) as EndTime 
from visit 
where StartTime between '2018-02-01' and '2018-02-02 23:59'
and cast(dateadd(minute,Duration,StartTime) as Time) >= '20:00' 
and cast(dateadd(minute,Duration,StartTime) as Time) <= '00:00'
```

Please assist. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get any result as TIME 00:00 is earlier than 20:00

Checks for 20:00 and 23:59 with a OR condition for 00:00

```
AND
(
        cast(dateadd(minute,Duration,StartTime) as Time) BETWEEN '20:00' AND '23:59'
    OR  cast(dateadd(minute,Duration,StartTime) as Time) = '00:00'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting data between two dates, I will not prefer `BETWEEN` clause. We can do this using `>=` and `<=` operators as shown below -

```
declare @visit table (visitid uniqueidentifier, StartTime datetime, duration int)
insert into @visit
select newid(), '2018-02-01 19:00:00', 60
union all
select newid(), '2018-02-01 20:00:00', 240
union all
select newid(), '2018-02-01 21:00:00', 120

Select VisitID, StartTime, duration, dateadd(minute,Duration,StartTime) as EndTime 
from @visit
where
    dateadd(minute,Duration,StartTime) >= '2018-02-01 20:00:00'
    and dateadd(minute,Duration,StartTime) <= '2018-02-02 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I have seen is that you are using an AND instead of an OR.

```
Select VisitID, StartTime, duration, dateadd(minute,Duration,StartTime) as EndTime 
from visit 
where StartTime between '2018-02-01' and '2018-02-02 23:59'
and (cast(dateadd(minute,Duration,StartTime) as Time) >= '20:00' 
or cast(dateadd(minute,Duration,StartTime) as Time) <= '00:00')
```